# How to work with ellipsis in bootstrap responsive table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

In a responsive table `text-overflow:ellipsis` is not working when the data increases in the `th` (as the `col-xs-2` width increases).

[image]

Code below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;">Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">Firstname</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"> Lastname</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">Age</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">City</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Anna</td>
        <td>Pitt</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>USA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> The text-overflow property only affects content that is overflowing a
>   block container element in its inline progression direction
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#wikiArticle)

For `text-overflow` to work, specifying `text-overflow: ellipsis` alone will not do any good - you should use the following styles together:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

```css
span, div, th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span>Inline element overflow ellipsis do not work</span>
<div>Block elements overflow ellipsis works</div>
<table>
  <tr><th>Table - Overflow test</th></tr>
  <tr><td>This is a long text</td><td>This is a long text</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

**Text Overflow in Table Layout**

So `text-overflow` applies to `block` elements but `td` is a `table-cell` element - tables are always *tricky* to deal with because they are rendered using the *default table layout algorithm*. The widths of the table and its cells are adjusted to fit their content.

1. Normally specifying the usual property for getting *ellipsis* may work:

   ```
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   ```
2. If they do not work or you begin to see the *table algorithm* do tricks on you,  then you can use them along with `max-width: 0`

   ```
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 0;
   ```

   ```css
   .table .text {
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     max-width: 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th class="col-xs-2 text">
             Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
             </th>
             <th class="col-xs-1">Firstname</th>
             <th class="col-xs-1">Lastname</th>
             <th class="col-xs-4">Age</th>
             <th class="col-xs-2">City</th>
             <th class="col-xs-2">Country</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Anna</td>
             <td>Pitt</td>
             <td>35</td>
             <td>New York</td>
             <td>USA</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
   ```
3. Another **hack** is to wrap the text in a `span` positioned `absolute` inside the `td` with `width: 100%` along with an `inline-block` *pseudo element*.

   ```css
   .table .text {
     position: relative;
   }

   .table .text span {
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
   }

   .text:before {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th class="col-xs-2 text">
               <span>
             Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</span>
             </th>
             <th class="col-xs-1">Firstname</th>
             <th class="col-xs-1">Lastname</th>
             <th class="col-xs-4">Age</th>
             <th class="col-xs-2">City</th>
             <th class="col-xs-2">Country</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Anna</td>
             <td>Pitt</td>
             <td>35</td>
             <td>New York</td>
             <td>USA</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
   ```

Comment: line-height:1;-webkit-line-clamp:1;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;  overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen thus far.

Comment: Nice trick about using position relative and absolute. My scenario was a little different but still worked. Thanks

Comment: nice! Solution #2 did the trick for me. I wanted to not set the max-width of table or cells to anything constraining, as I wanted them to grow/shrink with the table. Not sure why it works, but adding `max-width: 0;` like you said, did the job.

Answer (score 30):

As of Bootstrap 4 you can do the following using the `.text-truncate` class.

```
<th class="col-xs-2 d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">
```

More details found at 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

Comment: But if you have your table width set to fill the available width space (width: 100%), then this would constrain the cell width, rather than make it possible to grow and shrink with the table. @kukkuz's solution #2 worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

With Bootstrap 4, you can use the `.text-truncate` class. It automatically adds these styles for the relevant components.

```css
.text-truncate{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

then you can set the max-width for the element to get more reliable output.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion for bootstrap 4:

[Github Docs](https://gist.github.com/marcoskubis/4bf343928703824d85d0ec1b301f3a63)

```
.table.table-ellipsis tbody td {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5, you can do as others have mentioned by adding the `text-truncate` class to a `<td>`, for example:

```
<td class="text-truncate" style="max-width: 50px;">Some super long text...</td>
```

To show the full text, add this CSS style to show the text on hover:

```
tr > td:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: unset;
}
```