# Bootstrap 4 truncate long text inside a table in mobile devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a responsive table in order to use it both in Desktop and mobile devices.
The problem is that when the table loads long text it get truncated ruining the concept of 'responsive'.
I encountered into this problem only on the mobile platform, so here is a screenshot of the problem(if it can help...):
[image]

What is the best way to fix this problem?
I've tried many other tutorials but, unfortunately, no one has worked.

-- EDIT --
The HTML for the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>
    <th scope="col">Password</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {{#each users}}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{name}}</th>
    <td class="text"><span>{{email}}</span></td>
    <td class="text"><span>{{password}}</span></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I don't have any custom css, except the one for the background color.

Comment: If you want help I suggest you post the HTML for the table, You most likely have a issue with css there. If you're using custom css class please post them along with the HTML. We can't tell you exactly why you get this result with a simple screenshot.

Comment: Please check this link, it makes ellipsis on table content : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148127/how-to-work-with-ellipsis-in-bootstrap-table-responsive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the contacts app on your phone. You'll notice that it only shows the name on each line in an "index" view. From there, users will click on each user name to reveal additional details about each contact. This is what we call "progressive disclosure" for mobile apps.

Comment: So you suggest to change the whole design?

Comment: Yes, this is how we have to do things for "mobile apps". Portrait mode on phones are the most-difficult to design for. This is why we say that our design should be "mobile first." Start with portrait mode for a phone, and then work your way up. Alternatively, you could simply make your app only work for screens that are a minimum size.

Comment: Yeah, i think that your idea is the best here, the table will store very long strings(such as descriptions, names, etc.) so i just can't use a design like this.

Answer (score 8):

To truncate the text in an HTML table, you first figure out what's the maximum width (in pixels) you can allow on small screens and then apply the `text-truncate` class along with `max-width` style like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">
  Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
</span>
```

To truncate automatically, based on the available space, you need to restructure the whole thing into a Bootstrap grid. Then you can use this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 text-truncate">
    Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in tables things are different. specially with "table-responsive" class

Answer (score 3):

I tried next

```
<td width="70%" class="text-truncate" style="max-width: calc( 70 * 1vw )">
```

It seems to be working.

Comment: Why not just `style="max-width: 70vw;"`?