# Using Django tables 2, how do you cut off a long text field with an ellipsis?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am using [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I have a field that has really long text.

[image: django-table2 long text]

Which I would like to truncate like this:

[image: django-table2 shortened text]

It is a bootstrap table:

```
class EntryRecordTable(tables.Table):
    ...
    comment = tables.Column(accessor=A('Comment'))

    class Meta:
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered'}
        orderable = False
        empty_text = 'No entries for selected dates'
```

I have tried this answer about [truncating text in a bootstrap table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148127/how-to-work-with-ellipsis-in-bootstrap-table-responsive), but it makes all rows a single line and truncates a bit too much.
How can I do this in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by extending `Column` and overriding the `render` method:

```
class TruncatedTextColumn(tables.Column):
    '''A Column to limit to 100 characters and add an ellipsis'''
    def render(self, value):
        if len(value) > 102:
            return value[0:99] + '...'
        return str(value)
```

and usage:

```
comment = TruncatedTextColumn(accessor=A('Comment'))
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Where does this code go, though?

Comment: In `tables.py`....just add the class above then use it as a column in your table extended from `tables.Table`

Comment: Cool, thanks! I spent a while looking for a solution, and this seems like the most efficient.

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` is another option, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 7):

I am using truncatewords combined with tooltip:

```
comment = tables.TemplateColumn('<data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{record.comment}}">{{record.comment|truncatewords:5}}')
```