# CSS: text-overflow: ellipsis breaks layout

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to truncate text in `div.inbox-item-message` using `text-overflow:ellipsis`, but whenever the truncation happens, it breaks the layout.

On running the example below, you can see that the second item's text gets truncated and the layout gets messed up.

How to solve this?

```css
.inbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.inbox-item-display-picture {
    padding: 0;
}
.inbox-item-display-picture img {
    width: 100%
}
.inbox-item {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2%;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray;
}
.inbox-item:hover {
    background: lightblue;
    color: black;
}
.inbox-item-timestamp {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 75%;
}
.inbox-item-message {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.inbox-header {
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.inbox-header-actions {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"
        integrity="sha256-NuCn4IvuZXdBaFKJOAcsU2Q3ZpwbdFisd5dux4jkQ5w=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="chat-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox">
                    <div class="row inbox-header">
                        <div class="col inbox-header-title">
                            <span class="h5"> <span class="fa fa-comments"></span>
                                Conversations</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 inbox-header-actions">
                            <span class="fa fa-filter"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inbox-item">
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col inbox-item-title">
                                    <span>Chat #10</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                                    8:48 AM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col inbox-item-message">
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 1:</span> Hello, how are you?
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">2</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inbox-item">
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_employee_male-2-512.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col inbox-item-title">
                                    <span>Chat #11</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                                    8:50 AM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col inbox-item-message">
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 2:</span> Some really long message here lorem
                                    ipsum
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inbox-item">
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col inbox-item-title">
                                    <span>Chat #12</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                                    yesterday
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col inbox-item-message">
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 3:</span> Short message
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">3</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col" class="conversation">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.inbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.inbox-item-display-picture {
    padding: 0;
}
.inbox-item-display-picture img {
    width: 100%
}
.inbox-item {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2%;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray;
}
.inbox-item:hover {
    background: lightblue;
    color: black;
}
.inbox-item-timestamp {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 75%;
}
.inbox-item-message {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.inbox-header {
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.inbox-header-actions {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"
        integrity="sha256-NuCn4IvuZXdBaFKJOAcsU2Q3ZpwbdFisd5dux4jkQ5w=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="chat-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 inbox">
                    <div class="row inbox-header">
                        <div class="col-11 inbox-header-title">
                            <span class="h5"> <span class="fa fa-comments"></span>
                                Conversations</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1 inbox-header-actions">
                            <span class="fa fa-filter"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inbox-item">
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10 inbox-item-title">
                                    <span>Chat #10</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-timestamp">
                                    8:48 AM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-11 inbox-item-message">
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 1:</span> Hello, how are you?
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">2</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inbox-item">
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_employee_male-2-512.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10 inbox-item-title">
                                    <span>Chat #11</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-timestamp">
                                    8:50 AM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-11 inbox-item-message">
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 2:</span> Some really long message here lorem
                                    ipsum
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">1</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inbox-item">
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10 inbox-item-title">
                                    <span>Chat #12</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-timestamp">
                                    yesterday
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-11 inbox-item-message">
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 3:</span> Short message
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">3</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--TODO: <div class="col-12" class="conversation"></div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Update: If you really must let the columns be able to automatically resize (not set the `col-#`), you could wrap the contents of the message body inside something like this and this will also give you your expected resulted:

Source: [How to work with ellipsis in bootstrap responsive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148127/how-to-work-with-ellipsis-in-bootstrap-responsive-table)

```css
.inbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.inbox-item-display-picture {
  padding: 0;
}

.inbox-item-display-picture img {
  width: 100%
}

.inbox-item {
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2%;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray;
}

.inbox-item:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  color: black;
}

.inbox-item-timestamp {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.inbox-item-message {
  //  overflow: hidden;
  //  white-space: nowrap;
  //  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  //    line-height:1;
}

.hackyWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
}

.hackyWrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}

.inbox-header {
  padding: 3%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.inbox-header-actions {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha256-NuCn4IvuZXdBaFKJOAcsU2Q3ZpwbdFisd5dux4jkQ5w=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="chat-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 inbox">
          <div class="row inbox-header">
            <div class="col inbox-header-title">
              <span class="h5"> <span class="fa fa-comments"></span> Conversations
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 inbox-header-actions">
              <span class="fa fa-filter"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-item">
            <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
              <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox-item-title">
                  <span>Chat #10</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                  8:48 AM
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox-item-message">
                  <span class='hackyWrapper'>
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 1:</span> Hello, how are you?
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">2</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-item">
            <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
              <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_employee_male-2-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox-item-title">
                  <span>Chat #11</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                  8:50 AM
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox-item-message">
                  <span class='hackyWrapper'>
                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 2:</span> Some really long message here lorem Some really long message here lorem ipsum
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">1</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-item">
            <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
              <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox-item-title">
                  <span>Chat #12</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                  yesterday
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col inbox-item-message">
                  <span class='hackyWrapper'>

                                    <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 3:</span> Short message
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">3</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" class="conversation">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought `.col` could be used to automatically resize column based on other columnn's colspan. [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width)

Comment: Will look into it

Comment: @cyberpirate92 Updated! Found some threads with similar problems, there are/is hacky ways to accomplish this, but would be preferred to implicitly type the column width (bootstrap) as you already know the size you would like in your case, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add col class you should always add the colspan. for instance you have a col-2 and a col class inside your .row.inbox-item. if you add all the classes on the same level up you should come to a total of 12. So if you have two divs like in your example you should add the 10 you have left after your first .col-2 div to the other div and change .col to .col-10.

The same goes for you other places where you are missing cols. Like "col inbox-item-title" should be "col-8 inbox-item-title" since there is already a col-4 on the same level.

I tried your code you should edit your col class after the col-2 class div to col-10 to make it work.

Like this:

```
            <div class="row inbox-item">
                <div class="col-2 inbox-item-display-picture align-self-center">
                    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-round-flat-vol-1-1/36/user_account_profile_avatar_person_student_male-512.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8 inbox-item-title">
                            <span>Chat #10</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 inbox-item-timestamp">
                            8:48 AM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-10 inbox-item-message">
                            <span class="inbox-item-sender">Person 1:</span> Hello, how are you?
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 inbox-item-unreadcount">
                            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: row number 5 in my code block above. just to be clear :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width) states that elements having `col` will automatically resize based on sibling column's colspan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the real issue. it's the white-space: nowrap; If you have that css you need to give the parent div a min-width:0; so it doesn't break. See this: https://codepen.io/aj-foster/pen/emBYPW